# p:tabView tabIndex access

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tabview

I have a code like below.

```
<p:tabView value="#{bean.entityList}" id="tabView" var="item">
     <p:tab title="#{item.name}">
     .
     .
     .
     </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

I want to access the index of the tab just like datatable's rowIndexVar. How can I get the tab index?

Comment: widgetVar.activeIndex gives the current index

Comment: @rags This is the answer, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: thanks for reply but it's not the answer. I need like rowIndexVar of the datatable. widgetVar.activeIndex gives just current index. But I will use the index at render time to generate something else.

Comment: I am looking for same issue, can you find the solution?

Comment: no I couldn't found any solution for it. sorry @kirlisakal

Answer (score 1):

There is a very horrible workaround for this, which I don't recommend but it's the best I could come up with. It involves having a bit of Javascript to keep track of the tab count, and within each tab using more Javascript to generate the HTML that needs the tab index.

In the `<head>`of your page, initialise the tab counter;

```
<head>
  <script>
    // Global tab counter
    tabCount = -1;
  </script>
</head>
```

Then when you draw each tab, increment the counter. Within the tab, whenever you need the tab index, make a small script to generate the HTML with the index. For example:

```
<p:tabView value="#{bean.entityList}" id="tabView" var="item">
  <p:tab title="#{item.name}">
    <script>
      // Increment the tab counter
      tabCount++;
    </script>

    <!-- Now the tab content -->
    The index of this tab is:
      <script>
        document.write(tabCount);
      </script>
  </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

As I said, it's horrible and makes me wince whenever I see it, but it works.

Comment: The id of the tabs contains an 'index' as well. e.g. `<a href="#form:j_idt130:0:j_idt131" tabindex="-1">Car - Y25YIH5</a>` and `<a href="#form:j_idt130:2:j_idt131" tabindex="-1">Car - HSFY23H</a>` where the 0 and 2 are index (1 is in between them ofcourse ;-)) So you can parse that. Or you can do some small javascript that looks in the dom which index it has... So no need to keep track of a counter, but that is all client-side (I suspect the OP to need it server side)

Comment: Oh, and according to at least the 6.1 docs (did not check older versions), there is a `tabIndex` attribute

Comment: I'm not sure how much of the DOM is constructed within the `p:tab` tag when the page is being built, so it may be that the tab IDs aren't available by that point. But it might work.

Re. the `tabIndex` I'm pretty sure that it's related to the global tab order of elements on the web page, and not related to the tabs in the tabView.